# Pass PHP variable back to jQuery $.ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, post

**1. HTML**

I have an input requesting the user to enter their PIN code:

`<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="4" id="pin" />`

**2. javaScript**

When the user types in 4 characters, the jQuery function fires off an ajax call to process the PIN in a PHP file and return the corresponding site name:

```
$("input#pin").keyup(function() {
    var PIN = $("this").val();

    if (PIN.length == 4) {

        var dataString = "PIN=" + PIN;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pins.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(site)
                {
                    console.log("site name is:" + site);
                }
        });
    }
});
```

**3. PHP**

`pins.php` contains the following code:

```
<?php
$pin = $_POST["PIN"];

if ($pin == "faf9") {
    $site = "pgv";
}

echo $site;
?>
```

**Problem**

I cannot seem to get the value of `$site` back into the success function of the ajax call. Console log reports `null` as the value if the pin doesn't equal `faf9` and there is no log if  I enter the correct pin.

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change dataType to:

```
dataType: 'HTML',
```

That is all :)

Comment: Or change dataString to `dataString:{PIN:PIN}`

Answer (score 2):

your php returns a string but you're expecting a `JSON` object. Change your datatype attribute inside `$.ajax` function

Answer (score 2):

For `dataType: "json"`, you have to return json object.
If not, chang that type with appropriate one like `dataType: "html"` or `dataType: "text"`

Also, you need to initialize `$site` if you don't want null return value.

Comment: Initialize `$site` -- can you elaborate please?

Comment: @muppethead if it json `$site='{}';`. if html/text `$site='';`. Write the line before `if` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Make following modifications as:

- Replace `var PIN = $("this").val();` with `var PIN = $(this).val();`
- <del>Replace `var dataString = "PIN=" + PIN;` with `var dataString = PIN;`</del>
- Replace `dataType: "json",` with `dataType: "html",`

Comment: I'm pretty curious about why you changed your mind about this: `Replace var dataString = "PIN=" + PIN; with var dataString = PIN;`

Comment: I was assuming that you're using `$.post()` method in which you should pass a variable as `pin: PIN` and use it as `$_GET['pin']` on server-side. But you're using `$.ajax()`, I lately recognize hence did that change! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This m8 not be relevant to your exact problem, but i think you should use 
`$(this)` 
without quotations

Comment: Good catch. I do have `$(this)` in my code. Not sure why I added quotes here.